# time complexity of algorithm of table inversion

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Is there a way to find the time complexity of the following algorithm?

```
int n=A.length, temp;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++){
    temp =A[i][j];
    A[i][j]=A[j][i];
    A[j][i]=temp;
}
 }
}
```

Comment: Just count how often the swap-code is executed in total. It is `n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + 1`. So `sum_(i = 1)^n i` which is `(n^2 + n)/2`, so `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 3):

It's `O(n^2)`.

There is a nested loop (`i` goes from 0 to `n-1`; and for each `i`, `j` goes from `i+1` to `n`).

This is simply the number of unique pairs for all `i, j` in range `0 to n-1`.

The swapping is `O(1)`.